# Is it recommended to normalize a database for often repeating (long) strings?

Tags: database, database-normalization

Lets imagine a dataset that has multiple descriptions (0..N). You would normally solve that with a 1:N relation.

### Item

```
id | name

1  | item1

2  | item2
```

### Description

```
id | fk_item_id | description                                      | language

1  | 1          | Very important text that shouldnt be missed      | en

2  | 2          | Another important text that is very very useful  | en

3  | 2          | Very important text that shouldnt be missed      | en
```

As you can see, there is a duplicate text entry for id 1 and 3 in the description table. 
I have now the problem, that for 80% of my datasets the same description value is supplied which looks to me very unefficient.
Normally i would expect very different strings here but in fact, 80% of them are equal ...

My question: Is it a good idea to give the description a unique constraint even if there are long texts? Or is it better to leave this "unnormalized" ?

My concerns are about speed while importing this data, so checking if an particular string already exists may be expensive for hundred thousands items to import.

General: When is the best moment to move strings to an extra table? So my feeling tells me, for tags it makes absolutely sense since these are just short words which are repeating very often  ... but logical seen they are also just strings ...

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean, "give the description a unique constraint"? It's not unique. PS Replacing values by other values that are "ids" is not normalization (in either of its 2 senses, to 1NF or to higher NFs). When to do it is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless *you* define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best". [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I use a string table to make database more efficient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024048/should-i-use-a-string-table-to-make-database-more-efficient)

Comment: So, don't know whats not clear about the question ...yes the strings are not unique, but i could make them unique and instead of adding duplicate strings i could link to them if they are the same like i need in my current record ... the question was if that make sense at all or is this not a valid use case? The alternative is a description table where 80% of the records are the same ...

Comment: You say you don't know what's not clear then immediately you admit that you wrote X in the quote I gave when actually not X & you go on to clarify, so why do you say you don't know what's not clear? (Rhetorical.) Please just use enough words to be clear. Please clarify via edits, not comments.